# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040105 a=-1} errow with Material3 style error

Tags: android, android-xml, material-components-android

So, I have this button in my XML

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/whatsappHelpBtn"
            style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.IconButton.Outlined"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:insetTop="6dp"
            android:insetBottom="6dp"
            app:cornerRadius="4dp"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_whatsapp_primary"
            app:iconGravity="textEnd"
            app:iconTint="@null"
            app:strokeColor="#4DA198" />
```

This line

```
style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.IconButton.Outlined"
```

Making it throw this exception multiple times

```
Failed to inflate ColorStateList, leaving it to the framework
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040105 a=-1}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:529)
    at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.inflate(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:160)
    at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:125)
    at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.createFromXml(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:104)
    at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.inflateColorStateList(ResourcesCompat.java:262)
    at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getColorStateList(ResourcesCompat.java:236)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getColorStateList(ContextCompat.java:558)
    at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:48)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getColorStateList(TintTypedArray.java:179)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatBackgroundHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatBackgroundHelper.java:66)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:86)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:226)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:222)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1014)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1144)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1105)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1147)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1105)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:775)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
    at in.application.android.features.home.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:222)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8050)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8030)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3648)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3832)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2247)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7886)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:568)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045)
```

Any help would  be appreciated.